# Посоветуйте более оптимальный способ получения разницы во времени между днями

Tags: c#, unity3d

Написал небольшой скриптик, считающий разницу во времени между текущим моментов и будущим днем недели в секундах, т.к не нашел соответствующей команды для подобного результата. Может я плохо искал, но почему-то мне кажется, что решение моей проблему уже должно быть, может быть даже более оптимальное. Если такое есть, буду благодарен, если поделитесь.
В данном скрипте я получаю кол-во секунд до какого-то определенного дня недели, чтобы потом можно было их передать таймеру. Конкретной даты нет, есть только Now и дни недели

```
    private DateTime currentDate;
private DateTime futureDate;
private void OnEnable()
{
    currentDate = futureDate = DateTime.Now;
    StartCoroutine(CheckTime());
}

private IEnumerator CheckTime()
{
    while (futureDate.AddDays(1d).DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        futureDate = futureDate.AddDays(1d);
        yield return null;
    }
    while (futureDate.AddHours(1d).DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        futureDate = futureDate.AddHours(1d);
        yield return null;
    }
    while (futureDate.AddMinutes(1d).DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        futureDate = futureDate.AddMinutes(1d);
        yield return null;
    }
    while (futureDate.AddSeconds(1d).DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        futureDate = futureDate.AddSeconds(1d);
        yield return null;
    }
    Debug.LogError(futureDate.DayOfWeek); // считаем до секунды, сколько осталось времени
    Debug.LogError(futureDate.TimeOfDay); // до понедельника
}
```

Comment: `var seconds = (futureDate - currentDate).TotalSeconds;`

Comment: Это работает в том случает, когда известно futureDate. Если futureDate это какой-то абстрактный день недели, то его сначала нужно получить

Comment: тогда я не понял вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код не проверял, но по идее должно быть как-то так:

```
futureDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays((7 + (int) DayOfWeek.Monday - (int) Datetime.Today.DayOfWeek) % 7)
var seconds = (futureDate - DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds;
```

Спасибо aepot за вторую строчку.

Переводим разницу между искомым днём недели и текущим днём недели в положительное значение и берём по модулю 7, чтобы получилось число от 0 до 6. Это и будет искомое число дней, которое нужно добавить к текущей дате (с нулевым временем), для этого берём `Today`.
Ну и потом считаем разницу с `Now` и берём от неё секунды.

Ну, если я всё правильно понял.

Comment: Не знаю, так вы и задумывали ли, но ваше значение выдало -68897,48 сек, что равняется 19ч. Если рассматривать искомый результат как уже прошедшее время, то думаю это был бы правильный ответ, но поскольку мне необходимо было оставшееся время, т.е на данный момент по моим часам 4ч или 17270.98 сек, было бы правильнее заменить `(int) futuredate.DayOfWeek` на `(int) currentDate.DayOfWeek`
За исключением этого, большое спасибо :3

Comment: Да, я немного запутался, исправил. Там конечно или Now или Today справа должно быть )

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что это работает только с DateTime.Today (с Now не работает вроде)? Почему так? DateTime.Now возвращает же не только дату, но и время

Comment: Today это Now с нулевым временем